# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from opening files in the current tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

If I open a file in Visual Studio Code, it seems to open it in a kind of temporary state. I can see it's in this state due to the tab title being italic:

[image]

In this case, if I open another file, for example by clicking on a different file in the sidebar, it opens it in the current tab instead of a new one. It's only by double-clicking on a file that the tab gets out of this temporary state.

So is there an option I can use to make sure all files are always open in a new tab? I think it used to work like this but I must have accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcuts and it went into this mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's controlled by configuration option `Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview`.

Open settings by either main menu option `File > Preferences > Settings` or pressing `Ctrl+,` then search for "Enable Preview" and you will see the option. Uncheck the option to disable opening as a preview.

[image]

Also if you open the file by double click instead of click will be opened not-as-preview no matter the option; just pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable it in thr `settings.json` file:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```